# jQuery - Change 'normal div' content on drop of 'draggable div'

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have two div on my page.One is draggable and other is normal.

Draggable div:

```
<div id='draggable'>
     AAAAAA
</div>
```

Normal div:

```
<div id='dropbox'>
     BBBBBB
</div>
```

When 'draggable' div is dropped on 'dropbox' div, I want to append the contents of 'draggable' div to 'dropbox' div.

**So after drop , the contents of 'dropbox' div should be:**

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
```

Please guide me on how to do this using jQuery.

Comment: u visited jqueryui.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();//your drag handler
        $( "#dropbox" ).droppable({ //your drop handler
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).append( ui.draggable.html() );
            }
        });
    });
```

see Demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgmRm/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dropbox").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable.html());
    }
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with UI droppable

```
$(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).append( ui.draggable.html();
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`drop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) event of `droppable`:

```
$("#dropbox").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $("<div></div>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
})​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UrMrt/

Comment: can I please ask how to clone/append something from a get from the server like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086508/on-drop-clone-a-different-node-or-corresponding-element-from-the-server  for e.g `drop: function(event, ui) {
        /* get DIV from server and append */.text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);`